# R Boxplot: use different colors above and below the median

Tags: r

i'm trying to use two different colors in one Boxplot. My aim is to color the part above the median in red and the part underneath the median in green. 
At the moment i'm transforming the data and combining two boxplots in one plot. I think this is not an elegant solution. Maybe someone could help me?
Here is my R-code:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
x_l <- x
x_l[x_l > median(x)] <- median(x)
boxplot(x_l, whiskcol = "darkgreen", staplecol = "darkgreen", 
        boxcol = "darkgreen", col = "darkgreen", ylim = c(-3, 3), 
        outcol="darkgreen", lwd = 2, medcol="black")
x_u <- x
x_u[x_l < median(x)] <- median(x)
boxplot(x_u, whiskcol = "red", staplecol = "red",  boxcol = "red", col = "red",
        ylim = c(-3, 3), outcol="red", lwd = 2, medcol="black", add = TRUE)
```

[image: desired output image]

Thank you for helping, 
kindly regards,
 cawi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've found, your approach creates plots two medians, one for each half of the data. Instead, calculate one boxplot, without plotting it, and then modify the appropriate elements of the object, before using `bxp()` to plot:

```
set.seed(0)
x <- rnorm(100)
top <- bottom <- boxplot(x,plot=FALSE)
top$stats[1:2] <- top$stats[3]
top$out <- top$out[top$out >= top$stats[3]]
bottom$stats[4:5] <- bottom$stats[3]
bottom$out <- bottom$out[bottom$out <= bottom$stats[3]]
bxp(top, whiskcol = "darkgreen", staplecol = "darkgreen", 
        boxcol = "darkgreen", col = "darkgreen", ylim = c(-3, 3), 
        outcol="darkgreen", lwd = 2, medcol="black")
bxp(bottom, whiskcol = "red", staplecol = "red",  boxcol = "red", col = "red",
        ylim = c(-3, 3), outcol="red", lwd = 2, medcol="black", add = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Why are only the borders of the boxes colored?

Comment: adding  `boxfill = "red"` delivers the desired result

Comment: Thank you @cawi, this part of the code is absolutely essential.